# What is the purpose of compulsory sections?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, sections

I understand the benefit of `required: false` sections in MVC4. They are simply optional parts of a layout that will not display if the View does not contain them. But what is the benefit of `required: true` sections? Shouldn't something in a `required: true` section simply be put directly into the layout itself?

Comment: I'm not sure why this was down-voted. I think it's a reasonable question. Obviously there is a benefit and I want to know what that benefit is to aid my understanding of MVC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as an example, you could have a menu that would be required for each page but would also differ between controllers and/or areas.

Comment: So where would you store such a menu? As a section within every view? From what I understand, sections must be stored within views; is that incorrect? Sorry for the (probably stupid) questions, I'm just very new to MVC.

Comment: You'd probably store it as a partial view which you call and render from each view.

Comment: Can partial views be called as sections? And isn't calling and rendering essentially the same thing over and over in each view completely against the DRY principle?

Comment: Coming back to this question after gaining more experience... I see the light ;) Cheers.